# Problem with encoding UTF-8 chars in Windows with PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, encoding

I have the problem to show characters (äöü) in a utf8 format in Windows. In Linux there is no problem and everything is displayed correctly. I use at the second line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and further for importing and opening the shapefile:

```
base = os.path.basename(str(filename))
self.vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, base, "ogr")

layer = self.vlayer
provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer.select(provider.attributeIndexes())
addA=[] 
for elem in layer:
    attrs_r = elem.attributeMap()
    for (k,attr) in attrs_r.iteritems():
        addA.append(attr.toString())
```

I also tried:

```
addA.append(u'%s'%attr.toString())
```

and

```
layer.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
layer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'UTF-8')
```

But it has no effect and the characters are still not displayed correctly. Is there somehow a possibility to assign directly utf-8 to the shapefile?

Comment: This isn't really Windows specific.  I had the same Problem on Linux.  I think it just depends on how your Environment and your data is set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem:

```
layer = self.vlayer
provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer.select(provider.attributeIndexes())
addA=[] 
for elem in layer:
    attrs_r = elem.attributeMap()
    for (k,attr) in attrs_r.iteritems():
        unicodestr = unicode(attr.toString(), "utf-8")
        addA.append(unicodestr)
```

Now it is possible to use for example the German "Umlaute"